# Jquery change label text with inner input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am novice in Jquery. I want change label text when input box is changed. I have input box with name **email**.

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
```

When input box is changed I want to set label text to: **Send copy to my mail: mail@example.com**

```
<label for="sendCopy">
<input id="sendCopy" type="checkbox" checked="" name="copy"></input>
    Send copy to my mail
</label>
```

I have this Jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#email").keyup(function () {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        $("label[for='sendCopy']").val('Send copy to my mail: ' + email);
    });
});
```

but when **keyup** function is triggered label is changed right, but inner input is deleted.

```
<label for="sendCopy">
   Send copy to my mail mail@example.com
</label>
```

I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: `input` is a void element, it doesn't have closing tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the text of the label in a `span` to make it easier to select:

```js
$("#email").keyup(function() {
  $('label[for="sendCopy"] span').text('Send copy to my mail: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

<label for="sendCopy">
  <input id="sendCopy" type="checkbox" checked="" name="copy" />
  <span>Send copy to my mail</span>
</label>
```

Alternatively, you can keep the HTML as it is and amend the textNode directly.

```js
$("#email").keyup(function() {
  var textNodes = $('label[for="sendCopy"]').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  });
  textNodes[textNodes.length - 1].nodeValue = 'Send copy to my mail: ' + $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email" />

<label for="sendCopy">
  <input id="sendCopy" type="checkbox" checked="" name="copy" />
  Send copy to my mail
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I can´t change form structure because structure is generated by framework. For the second solution I try this but it works only when I change your code to:

`var tmp = $('label[for="sendCopy"]').contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        }).last();
        tmp[0].nodeValue = 'Send copy to my mail: ' + $(this).val();`

Comment: @LiborVymětalík you can use `$('label[for="sendCopy"]').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }).last().replaceWith("Send copy to my mail: " + $(this).val());
`

Comment: @LiborVymětalík ah yes, that was an error in my code. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: What if I have multiple dynamic inputs and can't address every single label? Why can't I use `$(this).parent().find('span').text()`?

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
<label for="sendCopy">
<input id="sendCopy" type="checkbox" checked="" name="copy"></input>
Send copy to my mail
</label>
```

To

```
<input id="sendCopy" type="checkbox" checked="" name="copy"></input>
<label for="sendCopy">
Send copy to my mail
</label>
```

Comment: I can´t change form structure because it generated by framework. Framework support change form template but in this case it will be unnecessary :)

Answer (score -1):

You are changing the contents of the label to the text, thus the input inside it is removed, the input is part of the value.

You have to put the input outside of the label, before it.

Comment: -1 You don't always have the means to change the html. Your answer doesn't answer the question, it should go into a comment.