# JS : Change label text with inner input

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternoon,

I was wondering if this issue : [Jquery change label text with inner input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360455/jquery-change-label-text-with-inner-input) was solvable with pure JavaScript ?

```
<div id="displaying" class="column">
    <label for="check_en_word"><input type="checkbox" id="check_en_word"
           onclick="changeVisibility('en_word')">mot anglais</label>
    <label for="check_fr_word"><input type="checkbox" id="check_fr_word"
           onclick="changeVisibility('fr_word')">mot français</label>
    <label for="check_en_definition"><input type="checkbox" id="check_en_definition"
           onclick="changeVisibility('en_definition')">définition anglaise</label>
    <label for="check_fr_definition"><input type="checkbox" id="check_fr_definition"
           onclick="changeVisibility('fr_definition')">définition française</label>
</div>
```

Here is what I've be trying, to no avail :

`console.log(document.getElementById('check_en_word').innerHTML);` : `<empty string>`
`console.log(document.getElementById('check_en_word').innerText);` : `<empty string>`
`console.log(document.getElementById('check_en_word').value);` : `on`
`console.log(document.getElementById('check_en_word').children.innerHTML);` : `undefined`
`console.log(document.getElementById('check_en_word').children.innerText);` : `undefined`
`console.log(document.getElementById('check_en_word').children.value);` : `undefined`

Thanks for reading that, and maybe answering.

Comment: Can you share the changeVisibility() function? That's were it should be changing the DOM at anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*check_en_word* is not the *id* of the label, it is the value of *for* attribute. So instead of `getElementById()` try using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) with [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[for=check_en_word]').textContent)
```

```html
<div id="displaying" class="column">
    <label for="check_en_word"><input type="checkbox" id="check_en_word"
           onclick="changeVisibility('en_word')">mot anglais</label>
    <label for="check_fr_word"><input type="checkbox" id="check_fr_word"
           onclick="changeVisibility('fr_word')">mot français</label>
    <label for="check_en_definition"><input type="checkbox" id="check_en_definition"
           onclick="changeVisibility('en_definition')">définition anglaise</label>
    <label for="check_fr_definition"><input type="checkbox" id="check_fr_definition"
           onclick="changeVisibility('fr_definition')">définition française</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It indeed logs the right text. Using it abruptly with ```    for (var [key, valuec] of inputs) { document.querySelector('[for=\''+key+'\']').textContent = valuec; }``` and my _inputs_ containing ids and associated text to replace. I'll have to use innerHTML on label and rewrite the same input, but changing the text. Good night !